# How can i find ink density(percentage) of pantone colors at a particular location in a pdf using any programming language?

Tags: pdf, color-space, cmyk, pantone

I need to programmatically calculate the percentage of Pantone colors at a particular point in the PDF. I've been looking for a solution for the last three months, but I was unable to put this feature into practice, and now I'm running out of time. I'm asking other developers for help. I'm using pdf.js to render and viewer.js to view the pdf.

i have tried few solutions but i am able to get percentage of one color if mentioned but not multiple colors if existed at that particular position.

Comment: You could render to separated output (1 image file per colour) then count the pixels which are non-zero in the area in each plate. Divide by the total number of pixels in that area to get the percentage of each ink. Be aware that if you require highly accurate results you will need to render at high resolution, which will be slow. A reasonable approximation should be quick though.

Comment: Hello @KenS, thanks for the reply as you said, we have multiple pages and large PDF files if we render multiple outputs the rendering time will be much higher and the overall application performance will be very slow. I'm looking for a solution which takes less time. Thank you.